# "Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero" but the variable has been added the value

Tags: php, html, loops

i make 2 arrays in PHP and i added value in array here

```
$num_a = array(2,4);
$num_b = array(8,12);
```

i make a conditional for calculate total value in array like this using foreach loop like this, i declared the `total = 0` so that there are no random numbers in it

```
    $total_a = 0;
    $total_b = 0;
    foreach($num_a as $key => $a){
        $total_a += $a;
        $total_b += $num_b;
    }
```

so i check the result but it's have an error

```
$result = $total_a/$total_b;
```

the error is :
`Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Division by zero in line 52` 
i know the error because it's cannot doing operation zero in value variable, but here i have fill the value using foreach loop, so how it can be? and how to solve this, thank you...

Comment: `$total_a = 0;` and then `foreach($total_a as ...)` makes no sense, you can not "iterate" over an integer.

Comment: should be `$total_b += $num_b[$key]`

Comment: @CBroe i write a wrong code i will edit this

Comment: @ITgoldman the error keep same sir !

Comment: int + array, $total_b += $num_b; it could not work

Comment: compare type-juggling , also this error is easy to debug, see the linked Q&A material.

Comment: @AlzildanAR  check these:    https://3v4l.org/h1X04  And https://3v4l.org/Hia9M

Comment: You don't need a loop here btw (look at that code, it's generating a nested array for `$total_b`) you can instead do `$result = array_sum($num_a) / array_sum($num_b)` - but you need to account for `array_sum($num_b)` being zero first.

Comment: also see array_sum() /E: right what @AD7six wrote.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
$total_b += $num_b;
```

by

```
$total_b += $num_b[$key];
```

Comment: this is more of a comment than and answer, leaving a pointer to a potential typo by the original author (the answer is to not make typos which is too broad for this sites scope).